# Delete zip files with matching directory name on Google drive usig colab

Tags: linux, bash, google-colaboratory

I have a directory with numerous zip files on Google drive. Some of those files have been extracted. Now the drive space is full so I need to clean up space. So I want to delete those zip files which have already been extracted. I'm using this command

```
!for x in `find "drive/My Drive/Refrence_Downloaded/" -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do rm $x.zip; done
```

But due to the space in the name "My Drive", `find` command splits the name into two paths. As it is Google drive, I cannot change it's name. How do I fix this?

Comment: @HarshWardhan : What is the status code negation operation (`!`) doing in front of the `for` command?

Comment: Put the $x.zip in double quotes.

Comment: @user1934428 It is needed in colab notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HarshWardhan : The `find` command itself does not split anything. The problem occurs when you do a

```
rm $x.zip
```

and `x` holds a path containing spaces. In this case, bash will split the arguments before handing them over to `rm`. Hence you need to avoid a

```
rm "$x.zip"
```

a word splitting.